# Subfigure referencing, wrong order

Tags: floats, cross-referencing, subfloats

I have problems with subfigure referencing. When I reference the main figure, the labeling in the reference is correct, but when I try to reference the subfigure, I get figure X+1, which is kind of weird:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\pagestyle{plain}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx, hyperref, caption, float}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!htp]
     \centering
     \caption{Impulse responses to policy shocks}\label{fig:impulses to policy shocks}
     \vspace{.05in}
     \parbox{\linewidth}{\footnotesize% 
   This figure displays.....}
       \subfigure[Something $\rightarrow$ Something.]{\label{fig:some_output}
          \includegraphics[width=.45\textwidth]{slope_output.eps}} 
      \subfigure[Something else $\rightarrow$ something.]{\label{fig:something_output}
          \includegraphics[width=.45\textwidth]{lvl_output.eps}}\\
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Then when i reference `\hyperref[]{Figure \ref{fig:some_output}}` I get the wrong figure number compared to what the simple reference \hyperref[]{Figure\ref{fig:impulses to policy shocks}}..

I tried a previous solution given here, but that did mess it up even more:

```
\makeatletter
\let\X@old@caption\caption
\def\X@caption@minusone{\expandafter\advance\csname c@\@captype\endcsname-1 }
\def\X@caption@br[#1]#2{\X@old@caption[#1]{#2}\X@caption@minusone}
\def\X@caption@nobr#1{\X@old@caption{#1}\X@caption@minusone}
\def\caption{\@ifnextchar[\X@caption@br\X@caption@nobr}
\makeatother
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: First of all: `\usepackage{hyperref}` should appear as the last package in almost any case. 2nd: You could use `\ref{}`, this should be sufficient and provide correct references and links. Using a different order of `\usepackage` messes up the correct linking.

Comment: Another advice: `subfigure` has been superseeded by `subfig`. Package `subcaption` would be another alternative.

Comment: Well, I put the `\usepackage{hyperref}` in the end of the preamble, but no luck. `\ref{}`vs `\hyperref{}` is no different. Also, I want the Figure X to be marked as a reference (colors and clickable) instead of only the number. Either way I still have issues provided your solution @ChristianHupfer. 

Regarding @Johannes_B solution, I did not understand what was meant by `subfigure` superseeded by `subfig`. Also I get 
`! Package subcaption Error: This package can't be used in cooperation (subcaption) with the subfigure package`..

Comment: IIRC, subfigure does not use \refstepcounter, therefore hyperref has nothing to target.  You need to use \hypertarget and \hyperlink.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Package `subfigure` has been superseded by package `subfig` a long
time ago because of some messy stuff (as you have seen). An alternative to `subfig` is package `subcaption` by
the author of `caption`. That means a maximum of compatibility.

Here is your example changed to use the `subfigure` environment,
which is basically a minipage.

You can use the `autoref` command provided by `hyperref` to save
some time. Remember to load package `hyperref` last in almost all cases.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\pagestyle{plain}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!htp]
    \centering
    \caption{Impulse responses to policy shocks}\label{fig:impulsesToPolicyShocks}
    \begin{subfigure}{0.49\textwidth}
    \centering
        \includegraphics[width=.45\textwidth]{slope_output.eps}
        \caption{Something $\rightarrow$ Something.}
        \label{fig:someOutput}
    \end{subfigure}\hfill
    \begin{subfigure}{0.49\textwidth}
    \centering
        \includegraphics[width=.45\textwidth]{lvl_output.eps}
        \caption{Something else $\rightarrow$ something.}
        \label{fig:somethingOutput}
    \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
\autoref{fig:impulsesToPolicyShocks} contains
\autoref{fig:someOutput} and \autoref{fig:somethingOutput}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks for tip on autoref